# ActiveX/IDL – how to export member functions from "ATL Simple Object" in OCX control?

Tags: visual-c++, activex, atl, idl

I have an ActiveX control in MSVC++10 which compiles into a .ocx. I have added another "ATL Simple Object" to this control, from which I want to export some functions.

If this library is called `OcxTest`, I have to perform the following steps to export a function:

1. **Declare** the function as protected member of the class `COcxTestCtrl` (as generated by the Project Wizard) in the file OcxTestCtrl.h.
2. **Define** the function in OcxTestCtrl.cpp.
3. **Add it to the Dispatch Map** in OcxTestCtrl.cpp:

   ```
   BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(COcxTestCtrl, COleControl)
        DISP_FUNCTION_ID(COcxTestCtrl, "Test", 1, Test, VT_I4, VTS_I4 VTS_I4)
   END_DISPATCH_MAP()
   ```
4. **Add it to the IDL** in OcxTest.idl at the following point:

   ```
   [ uuid(...), version(1.0),  control ]
       library OcxTestLib {
       importlib(STDOLE_TLB);
       [ uuid(...) ]
       dispinterface _DOcxTest {
           properties:
           methods:
               [id(1)] int Test(int x, int y);
   };
   ```

Now, I'm a bit lost as to where I define the exports for the other "ATL Simple Object" that I added to the project. I guess the first two steps are analogous to what I wrote. What about the other two steps?

1. **Is the definition of the Dispatch Map completely analogous to that of the main object?**
2. **Where in the IDL do I have to put the exported function?**

Comment: You are getting yourself into trouble by trying to do this by hand.  Functions are not exported in COM servers.  Use the wizards to get everything right.  Right-click the interface in the class view window, Add, Add Method.  You probably need to start over again to avoid the hand-typed code causing misery.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out the wizard. (Indeed it will freeze every time because I might have changed the IDL too much, but I was able to use it on a fresh project to see what it does. My question is therefore answered.)